# DNS Tunneling Explanation

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ssh-tunnel

I was reading http://dnstunnel.de/ which made a lot of sense until the Technical Setup part. Mind you, I'm a programmer so I'm not easily confused by things, but I was not sure about this part.

What am I setting up here, and where?

### Excerpt

**Technical Setup**

To delegate all requests to sub.example.com to ns.anothernameserver.com, you first have to delegate all requests to that server (NS record, line 1) and then send a so-called GLUE record (that is, glued to the record before because it's most likely the asking server will need this info as well) with your server's IP (line 2, A record).

```
 sub.example.com.              IN      NS      ns.anothernameserver.com.
 ns.anothernameserver.com.     IN      A       192.0.34.166
```

If you just have a DynDNS account and no static IP, you'd set up the delegation using a CNAME record. As mentioned above, CNAME is a canonical name (speak: an alias). So when a server gets back a CNAME instead of an A record (IP address) he continues to look up this hostname. That brings us to the following:

```
sub.example.com.              IN      NS      ns.extern.example.com.
ns.extern.example.com.        IN      CNAME   foo.bar.dyndns.org.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make use of tunneling through DNS, you need a server that the DNS tunneling queries will go to. Since these records are probably being passed through an intermediary caching server, they must conform to the DNS spec and query like a regular domain. Thus, all queries for data will have to end with the subdomain of your tunneling server which is referred to just like any other delegated DNS server.

Because this server isn't actually resolving real names, it needs to be a different address than your real DNS server, or a special combined server that will know to treat requests to the delegated subdomain differently.

Comment: Assume I have a Rackspace instance that can act as a DNS server, whhich I do — what then? I edited the DNS so my nameserver is up, and pointing to the instance.

Comment: @tekknolagi If you've set up everything correctly, use the client to make use of the tunnel.